# Conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ when $Y=2X+\epsilon$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm faced with the following question when computing the likelihood of an AR(1) model.

> Let $Y=2X+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$. Then the conditional probability density function of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $$\displaystyle f_{Y|X=x}(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-2x)^2}$$

This is the same as saying that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $\mathcal N(2x,\sigma^2)$. This is very intuitive and I have seen many sources asserting this and justifying it with mere handwaving.

I'm looking for a rigorous proof.

**EDIT**: see the picture below from Hamilton's *Time series analysis*

[image]

Comment: $Y,X,\epsilon$ are all jointly multivariate normal, and $Y$ is a linear transformation of $X$, (and $\epsilon$ although that gets marginalised out), if you are are happy that linear transformations of Gaussians are  again Gaussian random variables then just calculate the first two moments under the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[ \cdot | X = x \right]$

Comment: Is $\epsilon$ independent of $X$?.

Comment: @d.k.o. not necessarily

Comment: @Nadiels note $X$ may not be Gaussian.

Comment: If they are not independent, then the conditional distribution of $\epsilon$ given $X$ is not necessarily normal...

Comment: @GabrielRomon ah good point! Sorry I missed that

Comment: Usually such models assume that the conditional distribution of $\epsilon$ given $X$ is normal. Then your result is a trivial consequence of this assumption.

Comment: @d.k.o: I am very interested in this question right now as well... Could you elaborate? If you mean that $p(Y = y | X = x) = p(\epsilon = y - 2X | X = x) = p(\epsilon = y - 2x | X = x)$ then you need a replacement rule for conditional densities... how does that work? see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305908/likelihood-in-linear-regression and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457089/replacement-rule-for-conditional-density

Comment: @FabianWerner I've updated my post with an example of such computation.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: Yes, exactly! The sentence that bugs me most is 'conditioning on ... means treating ... as a constant'. This is absolutely NOT true! Everyone who claims this did not understand that there already EXISTS a clean definition of conditional density which does not that easily allow for a replacement rule. One needs to prove this rule. Also, I think that there is another mistake: one needs to assume that epsilon GIVEN X is normally distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (2017-10-24) *Amusing* downvote, purely for mathematical reasons, I am sure...

Recalling what the words really mean is a great help, as always... Here, to state that some function $$g:(y,x)\mapsto g(y,x)$$ is a conditional density of $Y$ conditionally on $X=x$ for every $x$, is, **by definition**, saying that, for every Borel subset $B$,

> $$P(Y\in B\mid X)=\int_Bg(y,X)dy$$

In turn, **the definition** of the conditional probability in the LHS is that, for every Borel subset $A$,

> $$E(P(Y\in B\mid X)\mathbf 1_A(X))=P(Y\in B,X\in A)$$

that is, assuming $X$ has PDF $f_X$ and $(X,Y)$ has PDF $f_{X,Y}$, $$\int_Af_X(x)\int_Bg(y,x)\,dy\,dx=\iint_{A\times B}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$ By identification, and since this relation must hold for every $(A,B)$, one gets the well-known identity

> $$g(y,x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$

In your case, $Y=2X+\epsilon$ where **one needs to assume that $\epsilon$ is independent of $X$**, with PDF $f_\epsilon$, then the change of variable $(x,y)\to(x,2x+z)$ yields $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X,\epsilon}(x,y-2x)=f_X(x)f_\epsilon(y-2x)$$ thus,

> $$g(y,x)=f_\epsilon(y-2x)$$

This is your formula, with $f_\epsilon$ the centered normal PDF of variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Sorry but did you even **read** my answer? Where do you see in it **anything** similar to what you write in your comment (and which you are simply repeating from your question)?

Comment: Regarding the variable $z$, it is only here to help you compute the PDF of $(X,Y)$. But maybe you are able to do this on your own? If you are not, why?

Comment: z is just a new symbol... that is what got me confused... I think what you are referring to is that if you have some bijection that is differentiable and $X_1, ..., X_n$ are RVs with common density $f_{X1, ..., X_n}$ then you get some formula of the kind $f_{\Phi(X_1, ..., X_n)}(x_1, ..., x_n) = f_{X_1, ..., X_n}(\Phi(x_1, ..., x_n))$ or maybe $\Phi^{-1}$ and up to constants but that is what you mean, right?

Comment: If you are already lost with this, this is what you should be asking about...  Why not fetch some notes on the subject or start with [the obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)?

Comment: "Here you claim exactly what I have written" Sorry but where do you see the monstrosity $$P((X,\epsilon)\in A\times(B-2x))$$ in what I wrote? Please be specific, or stop pouring nonsense on the page.

Comment: The factor is actually "important" if one wants to understand anything at all from the formula. These sleights of hand that you seem to be allowing to yourself, might be the reason why you are lost, in the end.

Comment: ((Comment by the OP, now deleted.))

Comment: I was missing the independence assumption ... It's then easy to view $(X,2X+\epsilon)$ as a smooth transformation of $(X,\epsilon)$ (the density of which is $f_X f_\epsilon$).