# Replacement rule for conditional density...

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume we have two random variables X,Y and a measurable function g such that $g(X,Y)$ and $X$ have a common density $f_{g(X,Y),X}$. Why is it true that for the conditional density $f_{g(X,Y)|X}(z|x)$ we have a replacement rule
$$f_{g(X,Y)|X}(z|x) = f_{g(x,Y)|X}(z|x) ?$$

Note: I suspect that there is the possible solution involving the differential of the conditional probability but this involves heavy math (and some L1 assumptions only to be able to write down the conditional probabilities / expectations) and the replacement rule for conditional expectation... Given that one needs this for things as simple as the derivation of the basic likelihood equitation for linear regression I highly doubt that there exists no simple way for deriving this...

Cheers,
FW